# Firebase authentication: How to deal with users using email addresses they don't own?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Scenario:

- Bob creates a Firebase account with email address alice@example.com which he doesn't own (either by accident or maliciously).
- Bob creates several private Firestore records (e.g. user comments/messages) that are linked to his user ID that only Bob should be able to read and write to.
- Alice tries to sign up and finds her email alice@example.com is already taken. How do we give Alice a user account linked to her email address without her having access to Bob's Firestore records and without Bob having access to her records she will go on to create?

Some ideas:

- You can send Alice the password reset email which will log out Bob but then Alice is going to see the records that Bob created when she logs in.
- You could use a Cloud function that 1) either deletes Bob's (email unverified) user or changes its email address 2) creates a new user for Alice with the email address verified flag set and send the password reset email.

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use one (or multiple!) of Firebase's auth mechanisms to help determine ownership.

1. You could use third-party auth (FB, Google, Twitter, Github) that would help clarify ownership of an e-mail address. (easiest, imo)
2. You can verify a user's email address via `firebase.auth().currentUser.sendEmailVerification()` https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/passing-state-in-email-actions
3. You could use an email link for signups: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth

From their docs:

> There are numerous benefits to signing in by email:
>
> ...
>
> - The ability to authenticate a user while also verifying that the user is the legitimate owner of an email address.

Comment: Thanks but you've not addressed how this solves the Bob/Alice scenario above where Bob has created records with a fake email which is the core of the question.

Comment: Sorry, the recommendation that I thought was implied but I didn't make clear enough (I was falling asleep while I wrote this) was to make sure that records can't be written until a user has verified their e-mail address. This is definitely a barrier for action in your site/app but seems like it'd give you the desired outcome.